# Dynamically access an object property array element in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have an object, that I would like to interact with dynamically. I would like to rename the game1_team1 in:

```
$default_value = $individual_match->field_match_game1_team1[0]['value'];
```

to be game1_team2, game2_team1, game2_team2, game3_team1, etc. Based on the loop they are in.

I have tried:

```
$dynamic = 'field_match_game'.$i.'_team'.$j;
$default_value = $individual_match->$dynamic[0]['value'];
```

but it returns

> Fatal error: Cannot use string offset
>   as an array

Update: Based on Saul's answer, I modified the code to:

```
$default_value = $individual_match->{'field_match_game'.$i.'_team'.$j}[0]['value'];
```

which got rid of the Fatal error, but doesn't return a value.

Comment: Why do people keep asking for variable variables? What the heck is wrong with arrays?

Comment: It is a 3rd party module that creates the object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$individual_match->field_match_game1team1[0]['value'] = 'hello1';

$i = 1;
$j = 1;

$default_value = $individual_match->{'field_match_game'.$i.'team'.$j}[0]['value'];
```

Comment: That doesn't cause the string offset error, but it doesn't return a value either.

Comment: That's because you dont have a value assigned in the first place. If you copied the full example then $default_value would contain 'hello1'. Do print_r on $individual_match and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

'Renaming' is not possible unless you create a new property, and delete the old one.
Access dynamic names like this:

```
$dynamic = "field_match_$i_team$j";
$default_value = $individual_match->$dynamic[0]['value'];
```

Note the `$` between `->` and `dynamic`.

Delete and create example:

```
$oldProperty = "field_match_1_team1";
$newProperty = "field_match_$i_team$j";
$hold = $individual_match->$oldProperty;
unset($individual_match->$oldProperty);
$individual_match->$newProperty = $hold;
```

Comment: Two challenges: 1. $dynamic = "field_match_$i_team$j"; doesn't seem to work because the variable is assumed to be $i_team... instead of $i. 2. The use of the $dynamic[0]['value'] returns "Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array"

Answer (score 0):

Look at this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php
You can list all object's properties in array and select only needed.