# Modify an entry of a property which is array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

What is the most quick way to change an entry of a property which is an array.

```
// Generates Illegal string offset ...
$this->propertyArray['index'] = 'xxx';
```

I forgot to mention that the property is accessed dynamically, here's a complete snippet:

```
class MyObject {
    public $dimensions = [
        'width' => 100,
        'height' => 200
    ];

    public function changeEntryOfArrayProperty($property, $entry, $value) {
        // Warning: Illegal string offset 'width'
        $this->$property[$entry] = $value;
    }
}

$obj = new MyObject();
// Warning: Illegal string offset 'width'
$obj->changeEntryOfArrayProperty('dimensions', 'width', 600);
```

Comment: Is the index is defined ? We can't help with only this line of code.

Comment: The only way you're getting "illegal string offset" is if that is not an array.

Comment: We can try to help you if you try to help us to better understand your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Maybe you could show the initialization of that `propertyArray` or put some extra code.

And as @Korvin says, maybe that's not an `Array` but a `String`? The methods [`is_array`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.is-array.php), [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php), [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-key-exists.php) and [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) may come in handy.

Comment: The question is edited, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change how you access a dynamic property - see [Dynamically access an object property array element in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008790/dynamically-access-an-object-property-array-element-in-php)

```
public function changeEntryOfArrayProperty($property, $entry, $value) {
    // Warning: Illegal string offset 'width'
    $this->{$property}[$entry] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the 'ArrayObject' quite useful for these sort of techniques. Alas,  I don't fully understand how it works the way it does. I suspect that it is a 'special object' known to PHP as it does things, as regards parsing array subscripts, that isn't available to 'ordinary' classes as far as i can tell.

I present the code. It may be useful.

```
<?php

class MyObject extends \ArrayObject {
//    public $dimensions = null;

    public function changeEntryOfArrayProperty($property, $entry, $value) {
        // Warning: Illegal string offset 'width'

        if (!isset($this->{$property})) {
            $this->{$property} = array();
        }
        $this->{$property}[$entry] = $value;
    }

    public function __construct($initValues =
             array('dimensions' => array('width' => 100,
                                           'height' => 200)))
    {
        parent::__construct($initValues, \ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
    }

}

$obj = new MyObject();
// Warning: Illegal string offset 'width'
$obj->changeEntryOfArrayProperty('dimensions', 'width', 600);

$obj->changeEntryOfArrayProperty('hello', 'there', 'world');

var_dump($obj);

var_dump($obj->dimensions['width']);

var_dump($obj->hello['there']);


// ------- access the properties and arrays directly... 
$obj->newProperty = array();
$obj->newProperty['NP1'] = 'new property 1';

var_dump($obj->newProperty, $obj->newProperty['NP1']);
```

Output:

```
object(MyObject)[1]
  public 'dimensions' => 
    array
      'width' => int 600
      'height' => int 200
  public 'hello' => 
    array
      'there' => string 'world' (length=5)

int 600

string 'world' (length=5)

array
  'NP1' => string 'new property 1' (length=14)

string 'new property 1' (length=14)
```